# DbContext dependency injection is conflicting with IHostedService when Application is starting

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I started my first Asp Net Core, a I know about `Spring Boot Application`, so I tried to put thing that I know in my new project.

I put dependency injection in my services, repositories. 
In service I put `Singleton` and repositories using `Transient`, but I change dbContext to be managed by the `Entity Framework`, and the error appeared.

First because services singleton, I changed them to Transient, but I also have create a background service to access other web service.

But it gave me error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cannot consume scoped service 'TelegestaoAPI.Models.VLUMINUM_TELEGESTAOContext' from singleton 'Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostedService'.'
```

My startup services are like this:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        _connString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("VluminumDataBase");

        services.
            AddMvc(option => option.EnableEndpointRouting = false).
            SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0);

        services.
            AddMvc().
            ConfigureApiBehaviorOptions(options => { options.SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter = true; }).
            SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0);

        services.
            AddAuthentication(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IIS.IISServerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

        services.
            Configure<IISServerOptions>(options => { options.AutomaticAuthentication = false; });

        services.
            Configure<IISOptions>(options => { options.ForwardClientCertificate = false; });

        services.
            Configure<GzipCompressionProviderOptions>(options => options.Level = System.IO.Compression.CompressionLevel.Optimal);

        services.
            AddResponseCompression(options =>
        {
            options.Providers.Add<GzipCompressionProvider>();
        });

        services.AddControllersWithViews()
            .AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
            options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
        );

        services.
            AddMvc().
            AddJsonOptions(options =>
        {
            options.JsonSerializerOptions.IgnoreNullValues = true;
        });

        services.AddGlobalExceptionHandlerMiddleware();

        services.AddDbContext<VLUMINUM_TELEGESTAOContext>();

        services.AddHostedService<TaskLeituraService>();

        services.AddTransient<ComandoEnviadoFilter>();

        services.AddTransient<ClienteService>();
        services.AddTransient<ComandoEnviadoService>();
        services.AddTransient<FotoService>();
        services.AddTransient<LeituraService>();
        services.AddTransient<MunicipioService>();
        services.AddTransient<PontoService>();
        services.AddTransient<PosteService>();
        services.AddTransient<TipoComandoService>();
        services.AddTransient<TipoPosteService>();
        services.AddTransient<TipoComandoService>();
        services.AddTransient<UltimaLeituraService>();
        services.AddTransient<UsuarioService>();

        services.AddTransient<ClienteRepository>();
        services.AddTransient<ComandoEnviadoRepository>();
        services.AddTransient<FotoRepository>();
        services.AddTransient<LeituraRepository>();
        services.AddTransient<MunicipioRepository>();
        services.AddTransient<PontoRepository>();
        services.AddTransient<PosteRepository>();
        services.AddTransient<TipoComandoRepository>();
        services.AddTransient<TipoPosteRepository>();
        services.AddTransient<UltimaLeituraRepository>();
        services.AddTransient<UsuarioRepository>();
    }
```

My background service:

```
public class TaskLeituraService : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly LeituraService _leituraService;
    private readonly ILogger<TaskLeituraService> _logger;

    public TaskLeituraService(LeituraService leituraService, ILogger<TaskLeituraService> logger)
    {
        _leituraService = leituraService;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            stoppingToken.Register(() => _logger.LogDebug("LeituraTaskService esta parando"));
            await ExecuteTaskLeitura();
        }
    }

    private async Task ExecuteTaskLeitura()
    {
        try
        {
            _logger.LogDebug($"{DateTime.Now} - Enviando comando leitura das fotocélulas");
            await _leituraService.ExecuteTaskLeituraFotocelulaAsync();
            _logger.LogDebug($"{DateTime.Now} - Finalizando comando leitura das fotocélulas");
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

And here is how I inject dbContext

```
public class FotoRepository : GenericRepository
{
    private readonly VLUMINUM_TELEGESTAOContext _dbContext;
    public FotoRepository(VLUMINUM_TELEGESTAOContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }
}
```

Comment: This https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#consuming-a-scoped-service-in-a-background-task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not inject scoped/transiet services to your `HostedService`, instead you will have to inject `IServiceProvider` and then create a scope like this:

```
public class TaskLeituraService : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly ILogger<TaskLeituraService> _logger;

    public ConsumeScopedServiceHostedService(IServiceProvider services, 
        ILogger<TaskLeituraService> logger)
    {
        Services = services;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public IServiceProvider Services { get; }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        using (var scope = Services.CreateScope())
        {
            var _leituraService= 
                scope.ServiceProvider
                    .GetRequiredService<LeituraService>();
            while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                stoppingToken.Register(() => _logger.LogDebug("LeituraTaskService esta parando"));
                await ExecuteTaskLeitura(_leituraService);
            }
        }
        await Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private async Task ExecuteTaskLeitura(LeituraService _leituraService)
    {
        try
        {
            _logger.LogDebug($"{DateTime.Now} - Enviando comando leitura das fotocélulas");
            await _leituraService.ExecuteTaskLeituraFotocelulaAsync();
            _logger.LogDebug($"{DateTime.Now} - Finalizando comando leitura das fotocélulas");
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Be aware that this approach essentially creates a "singleton scope" that will be oblivious to subsequent state changes from the rest of the application after it's first created.

Answer (score 1):

You can either change your `DbContext` to be a singleton:

```cs
services.AddDbContext<VLUMINUM_TELEGESTAOContext>(ServiceLifetime.Singleton);
```

Reference: [Entity Framework contexts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection#entity-framework-contexts)

Or create a scope manually in your background service to resolve it:

```cs
private readonly IServiceProvider _services { get; }

public TaskLeituraService(IServiceProvider services, ILogger<TaskLeituraService> logger)
{
    _services = services;
    _logger = logger;
}

private async Task ExecuteTaskLeitura()
{
    try
    {
        ⋮
        using (var scope = _services.CreateScope())
        {
            var leituraService = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<LeituraService>();
            await leituraService.ExecuteTaskLeituraFotocelulaAsync();
        }
        ⋮
    }
}
```

Reference: [Consuming a scoped service in a background task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services#consuming-a-scoped-service-in-a-background-task)

**NOTE:**

While it's possible to manually create a scope like this, it's typically not recommended:

> It's dangerous to resolve a scoped service from a singleton. It may cause the service to have incorrect state when processing subsequent requests.

Reference: [Singleton](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection#singleton)